# Can I get a boarding pass for a different airline in the transit area of Delhi Airport without going through immigration?

Tags: air-travel, transit, tickets, del

I am an Indian Citizen travelling from Dubai to Queenstown, NZ via Delhi with Handbaggage by different airlines. Have only three hours transit time. 
Can I get the Singapore/Queenstown Boarding Passes in Delhi in the Airside without going through immigration process twice?

Comment: Is that one or two reservations?

Comment: You can get a boarding pass online.

Comment: @Calchas I think ptityeti was going to say the OP would get both boarding passes From the first airport so he wouldn't have to go to the desk in Delhi at all.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be possible:

> An agent from the hotel met us at the arrival gate. He walked us to the transit desk. He confirmed that our luggage had transferred. He gave us new boarding passes. All this took about an hour. He had our passports and bag claim tags, which made us a little nervous, but he was in the same area as us the whole time so we could see him working on our behalf.

[(TripAdvisor)](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g304551-d2193653-r145246705-Holiday_Inn_Express_New_Delhi_International_Airport_Terminal_3-New_Delhi_Nationa.html#) and I doubt the situation has detriorated.

Earlier in the narrative the blogger advised *we had two different reservations in two different systems* and *skipped the transit visa step*.